# make ajax call after remove element from dom - jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

when I click on `.main-li` I remove all elements of `.sub-ul`, but when I click many times quickly on the button the remove is done then ajax call is running.

```
$(document).on('click','.main-li', function(){
    if($(this).children('ul').children('li').remove()){
        var topics = data;
        var sectionId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.get('{{ GET_ILOS }}/'+select.value+'/'+sectionId, function(data){
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function( key, value ) {
                var Input = '<li class="sub-li" data-id="'+value.id+'"  id="btn-li"> "'+value.name+'" </li>';
                $('#sub-'+value.section_id).append(Input);
                Input = '';
            });

        });

        $(this).find('.sub-ul').addClass('show');
        $(this).siblings().children('ul').removeClass('show');
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the remove is done then ajax call is running.`  - that is what the code does. What is expected behaviour?

Comment: Means you want: first make ajax call, then remove element. Or first remove element, then make ajax call?

Comment: @mplungjan as I understand the issue: click on button->ajax->update UI (works).  But click on button->1st ajax->click 2nd on button->2nd ajax->1st update->2nd update  (or even 2nd update->1st update).

Comment: You might like to disable click events while the previous ajax call is running.

Comment: when i click many times on button  javascript store ajax call to api and execute remove element  then javascript execute api stored functions

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).